# Referencing Bin In CronTab

Tags: linux, bash, cron, cron-task

When I run each of the following commands, they all work successfully. But when I put it in the following Cron job, it doesn't run. Please help:

```
35 14 20 6 2 rm //var/opt/dsdw-raw/dbo.mb_membership/LOAD00000001.csv && sleep 2 && \
aws s3 sync s3://ams-inbound-data-strategy/dbo.mb_membership/ //var/opt/dsdw-raw/dbo.mb_membership/ \
--exclude '*.dfm' && sleep 1 && /bin/sh /home/ec2-user/skippedrec.sh && \
sleep 10 export PATH=$PATH:/var/opt/mlcp/bin && sleep 1 && mlcp.sh import \
 -options_file /var/opt/dsdw-opt/load-ams-mb_membership.opt
```

Comment: In general for cron jobs, the best solution is to put all your commands into a batch file.  Then, you can specify the correct shell to use (which may be your problem) and test it all out at the command line.  Then, after you're tested it, you just add the one line command to call the script into cron.

Comment: There are *far* too many variables here to allow for a diagnosis. (What environment variables does your `aws` command need to run? You should, in general, be setting things like PATH needed everywhere at the very top of the crontab, before any job specifications at all).

Comment: Also, you need a command separator between the `sleep 10` and the `export PATH`.

Comment: that said, I'd argue that this isn't a software development question at all, and is rather about using OS-provided features (and would thus be a better fit at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com)). And even if it *were* a development question, it wouldn't be a **bash** question unless your crontab file contains an appropriate `SHELL=` assignment -- as the default shell is `/bin/sh`.

Comment: BTW, prefixing a command with something like `exec 2>/tmp/cron.log; set -x;` goes a long way towards enabling debugging, if you don't have working mail delivery set up on your system to get logs mailed from crond on failure.

Answer (score 0):

Cronjobs must appear on a single line in the crontab. They cannot be continued onto multiple lines with a backslash.

If your cronjob is complicated enough that you feel the need to use backslashes, you should probably move it into a separate shell script, then execute that script from the cronjob (e.g, `35 14 20 6 2 /bin/sh /path/to/script.sh`). This will also make it possible for you to test the script without running it from cron!